Local and Cloud syncing between drives in Windows
So I read computer organization book. It said there is chapter about Memory Hierarchy. As the capacity larger and cheaper, the Read and Write speed became slower, and vice versa.
So, I have my laptop with these memories (hierarchical):

RAM (8GB) (Fastest)
SSD (512GB) (Moderate)
HDD 5400RPM (1TB) (Slower)
Google Drive (Slowest, depends on internet bandwidth but mostly slowest.)

So I expect there is mapping like this:
SSD/MyFolderA <-> HDD/SyncFromSSD/MyFolderA <-> GD/SyncFromHDD/MyFolderA

As the book mentioned, SSD has wear out when performing write operations (becaming degradation performance and reliability) but not applied for read operations.
Even though so, why the GD synced by HDD instead of SSD. The answer is, it's bidirectional syncing. Therefore there is chance I can write a file from HDD or GD that still make SSD wear out.
I have utilities for GD syncing between local drive, but have no idea for local syncing between SSD and HDD. How do I apply this bidirectional syncing architecture?

SSDs currently (and since years ago) have the same or better life expectancy than HDDs. Do you worry about HDDs? Apparently not so you shouldn't worry about SSDs. Just use them as you'd normally use any old HDD.

"As the capacity larger and cheaper, the Read and Write speed became slower, and vice versa." - This is false.  DDR5 is substantially faster than say DDR2 and DDR5 smallest capacity exceed that of the maximum capacity of DDR2.  How old is this book? This book doesn't seem relevant in 2024.

@ChanganAuto HDD works on electromagnetic, according physic yeah there is still lifetime for magnet and vulnerable by mechanic event, so I avoid any phyiscal damage to HDD. About worryness like what? Disk failure? I hope that data already synced on GD.

I've lost more SSDs to random failures than wear, though admittedly both of those were bundled with cheap mini PCs. Wear's practically an overblown failure mode

@JourneymanGeek what do you mean by random failures?

Barely used drives dying early and completely

@JourneymanGeek but barely using SSD or archiving SSD for long term without any refresh of electrical charge for some periods is basically moving data (write operations) from past to future. Therefore I can say it's died because of write operations.

Different failure mode, and good SSDs go read only, these were not. I've been advising people for the better part of a decade that SSDs don't need to be coddled. Heck I'm picking up an old PC to fix up this weekend, and I'm likely going to run a decade old SSD for testing/boot that I'd been running till 2 years ago

@JourneymanGeek Okay, if SSD don't need to be coddled, then another reason my architecture GD still read the data from HDD instead of SSD is, to not bother SSD from using SWAP. I'm afraid if that pipeline sync bother SSD I/O operations during using virtual memory.

SSD is perfect for swap though, its fast and random access. Excess/enough ram of naturally better but SSDs are a good place for it

I changed my plan from bidirectional sync to high availability folder that applying redundancy 3-2-1 rule backup (store on SSD, store on HDD, store on Cloud). Therefore it's one way sync. Where a folder in SSD automatically sync to HDD and GD.
Actually, there is built-in feature in Windows called Storage Spaces, but it's only supported between disks redundancy instead of partitions redundancy or folders redundancy.
I Use built-in Windows features to do this, they are robocopy for syncing and Task Scheduler for trigger syncing automatically.
For 3rd party app prerequisite, just install official Google Drive for Windows and then mount with letter G:
Don't forget change Google Drive cache path to HDD with maximum allocation unit to saving SSD write durability.
Here is how to perform setup:

Create SSD partition exclusively for auto sync with drive letter D: and add new folder D:\ssd-sync and D:\ssd-sync\robocopy_autosync .

Create VHD file image inside HDD drive with fixed size same as SSD partition size, then mounting with letter F: and add new folder F:\vhd-sync.



Why not direct folder inside HDD drive? Like E:\hdd-sync ? It's because VHD file image is easier and faster to transfer for backup purpose compared to moving many small files in KB unit in a HDD drive folder which is slower because of mechanical part and low performance IOPS. HDD transfer is actually faster if it's reading a single unit big file compared to many files with KB unit.


Recommended: Before "Create VHD file image inside HDD drive", you can make transfer faster in HDD with allocating special partition with size same as VHD size, allocation unit must be set to maximum which is 2M instead of default 4096, keep filesystem default NTFS. Mount with letter E: and create VHD file with fixed size with name E:/hdd-to-vhd.vhd. That partition is intended for exclusively putting VHD inside HDD drive with cluster size 2M which is faster access.


Create folder G:\My Drive\high-availability-folder\gd-sync.

Create auto_sync.bat and save it into D:\ssd-sync\robocopy_autosync\auto_sync.bat:


robocopy D:\ssd-sync F:\vhd-sync /E /MIR /TEE /LOG+:D:\ssd-sync\robocopy_autosync\ssd_to_vhd.txt /V
robocopy D:\ssd-sync "G:\My Drive\high-availability-folder\gd-sync" /E /MIR /TEE /LOG+:D:\ssd-sync\robocopy_autosync\ssd_to_gd.txt /V


Then create auto_sync.xml, save it, and Import Task Scheduler:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2024-05-09T16:29:45.6364263</Date>
    <Author>LAPTOP-DJH6CVKH\User</Author>
    <URI>\Robocopy\robocopy_autosync</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <Delay>PT1S</Delay>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-170095007-379780964-48905099-1001</UserId>
      <LogonType>S4U</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>cmd</Command>
      <Arguments>/C "D:\ssd-sync\robocopy_autosync\auto_sync.bat"</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>

That scheduler is triggered for every 1 minute, so basically it's syncing every minute. The action it made is running the auto_sync.bat script.

So, why not syncing with Google Drive app feature? Because it doesn't support file and folder exclusion.

At the end, it would be looks like this:

If you are annoyed about too many full disk displayed on explorer, you can hide it. I asserted again, it's hiding, not disabling. Therefore you still can access hidden drive in explorer with full path without worrying disabled. This #4 options what I did: https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/hide-drives-windows.html

I still can access with typing full path of E:/hdd_to_vhd.vhd to backup to another place like through network.
