Do Mounting VHD on HDD can speed up access time in Windows?
As we know HDD is slower in term of read and write access time. Actually, it's not that slower if a transfered file is big size compared to multiple files with small size in KB unit being transfered.
Windows has option to add VHD let's say with fixed size 128 GB. Then we allocate partition (let's say drive D:\ exclusively for the VHD with same size 128GB with allocation unit as big as possible to represent one fragment since only there is one file which is VHD.
Optionally, we can defragment HDD first before allocation.
Then we mount the VHD as disk, init the disk as GPT then allocate simple volume partition with letter E:\.
So, will this increasing performance actually? I think so because what OS and HDD see one unit file which is VHD. So there is only one modification file.

Another critical factor is IOPS since a mechanical HDD has tens of IOPS versus the tens of thousands to hundreds of thousands of IOPS an SSD has (while not applicable to this question, IOPS is why an OS running from an SSD will always perform better than if the same OS was installed on a mechanical HDD)

If you're going to this, and actually benchmark, back in the day there was an application called jkdefrag that had a variety of defrag options - if you could find a modern day application that could make files contagious and pack both the VHD and its contents to the front or rear of the drive, it might have an impact. Its just a bit of an odd way to try to squeeze performance tho. I'd also look at short stroking - using 'part' of a HDD to improve seek speeds for something like this


So, will this increasing performance actually? I think so because what OS and HDD see are one unit file which is VHD. So there is only one modification file.

Unlikely.
The HDD doesn't care about files at all. It only cares about head movements – whether the data is linear or whether it's scattered around. In that regard, updating small chunks of a large file that are all over the place is exactly the same as updating small individual files all over the place.
So while the VHD file itself looks like a single linear allocation within D:\ (but so does an actual partition!), its contents that are used by the OS aren't nicely packed – the small files inside the VHD are still scattered around within the VHD's space, and when you're working with them, the HDD still has to seek from one file to another; from one extent to another; etc. It does not change anything that those seeks remain "inside the VHD" – physically they're still done across the entire 128 GB area and it still takes the same amount of time.
And of course, the OS still sees multiple files – in the mounted VHD. When you're working with the contents of the VHD-mounted E:\, you are not bypassing anything; if they were many small files before, they're still many small files after, and because the VHD has an NTFS filesystem like a real HDD, the OS still has to update their metadata in the same way, etc.
(In fact, the OS may now have to update the metadata twice, once for the VHD's filesystem and again for the physical partition's.)

As we know HDD is slower in term of read and write access time. Actually, it's not that slower if a transfered file is big size compared to multiple files with small size in KB unit being transfered.

It's all about seek time, i.e. the time it takes to mechanically move the read/write heads from A to B (which is essentially wasted time as the HDD can't transfer data while seeking). I've seen SSDs that had only half the throughput than the HDD they replaced, but they still felt faster because they had 0 seek time.
If there weren't any seeking necessary – e.g. if you picked up a whole .vhd and started copying it elsewhere – then it would be indeed faster than copying the individual files (and a good HDD could even outrun a cheap QLC SSD). So that's maybe the only possible advantage of your "full-size VHD" plan. But you can already do that with a partition; there are tools to copy partitions as single units (even tools to copy a partition into a .vhd).

I see, I forgot about what OS sees when VHD mounted which is still small multiple files. Yeah the only advantage of full-size VHD plan is faster backup plan. But still useless since there are many tools to convert partition into VHD. But wait, if I need to convert that's mean there is still extra process? Therefore it's slower backup plan compared to backing up directly full-sized VHD to another place?

The slowest part is just opening the app. Even if there is a "conversion" being done to the app's image format (whether VHD or some other), there just isn't much processing involved in it – and it's all done during the copying anyway – so it adds maybe 0.01 second per gigabyte... (And, to be honest, if backing up a 128+ GB partition is something you do very often, then copying a VHD is still one of the slowest methods – there are much better ways to do a periodic backup.)

How about size cost? Suppose there is no conversion progress, means just the partition into raw file of partition image being moved to the another computer. That's mean I need addition another temporary storage that has same size as the partition to hold it as single raw file of partition image so that I can transfer it through network. I never heard the partition itself is directly transfered through network. I only heard the partition is cloned between partition and unallocated partition which is offline.

That's been done many times. Not as simple as dropping a .vhd across a SMB file share, but in the end it's still just data being read from partition A and data being written to partition B – some disk-cloning software has it as a built-in feature, and on Linux it might just be something like cat /dev/sdb2 | ssh root@destination 'cat > /dev/sde2'.

I think in Linux it's possible like using dd command as the Linux threat everything as file. Where the input of the command like /dev/sda1 and the output is /mnt/nfs/sda1. How about Windows?

In conclusion, I think I'm still planning full-VHD plan. Unlike linux, there is built-in tools to moving partition flexibly especially through network. It seems Windows need third-party app to do that. About metadata update twice, yeah there is a bit overhead. I believe Windows has cache mechanism to do that, so it wouldn't be looks like update dummy HDD drive metadata for every time VHD drive update.

From experience(have surroundings set like this, desktop and servers), it will slow down any (hdd, ssd, m2) by 20-30% in average, you will never get full drive speed where vhd/vhdx is mounted.

@Danijel did you consider "allocation unit size" a.k.a. "cluster size" of every disks? Bigger cluster size means require less IOPS to access the VHD.

For redundancy purposes, I think it's understandable why I use VHD instead of direct HDD. Since I don't write my personal data to HDD directly, R/W speed and IOPS don't matter, but it's written by the redundator that the source comes from an SSD. It's related to my answer to another question: https://superuser.com/questions/1841771/local-and-cloud-syncing-between-drives-in-windows/1841903#1841903

Yes, depending on purpose,...gaming ie,...but if vhd(x) compared to, direct write will always be faster(at least in my tests), you can also slip them too(ie 3 diff drives), but again virtual will be slower then direct slip write
